# Change all forms sizes (Find & Replace)

Tags: c#, regex, visual-studio, winforms

I want to change the size of all forms in my desktop solution. I am sure I need to change in the designer file of every form a line like below:

```
this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(932, 620);
```

to the one below

```
this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(1366, 768);
```

These forms currently have different sizes but I want all of them to have same size. I tried a search replace but that doesnt work because the sizes for each from are different. I am think maybe if I search by regular expression it might work but have no clue about the regex needed to find all occurrences and replace them.

I am using VS2019 and it's winforms. Anyone please help.

Comment: Why do you want to hardcode this resolution? What if a user has a smaller screen or doesn't want to run the app fullscreen? What regex have you tried? Replacing `this.ClientSize = (.*);` with what you want should work...

Comment: `CTRL + H`, then search for `this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size\(.*\)` and replace with `this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(1366, 768);`

Comment: I appreciate your response. So my objective is to have all forms start off as maximised but when a user Clicks a restore button on the form the form should restore to the same design size (1366, 768). I am trying to avoid an unpleasant look and feel issue where one for restores to one size and the other to another size. Is this the right approach I am taking?

Comment: Usually, a Window is restored to the size the User set it. It's a User preference. Unless you want to set the MinimumSize...

Comment: *"I tried a search replace but that doesnt work because the sizes for each from are different"*. The F&R dialogue supports regular expressions so you should look into that. That will enable you to search for specific text containing any numbers.

Comment: That said, how many forms do you have? How hard would it be to just F&R "this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(" and then paste in the numbers?

Comment: There are quite many across several projects in that solution

Comment: If all the forms should have the same size, it basically means you need to use a shared settings for all the forms and bind the Size property to that setting. Another option is deriving from a base form and setting such properties in the base form.

Comment: To apply Jimi's answer, make sure you check "Use regular expressions" in find/replace window.

Answer (score 2):

Make your Find/Replace window look like this:

[image: Find and replace dialog]

- Find: `\.ClientSize = new System\.Drawing\.Size\(\d+, \d+\)`
- Repl: `.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(1366, 768)`
- Ensure that <kbd>.*</kbd> button is highlighted